# Can't access appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Before you mark this question as a duplicate:
I have tried pretty much every solution from other questions here.
I want to remove a previously appended element, but the code for that isn't executed. Maybe, you can also tell me a more beautiful way to store the content in var $content.

```js
var messageBoxCount = 0;
function createMessageBox(message) {
  messageBoxCount++;
  var $content = $("<div id='messageBox"+messageBoxCount+"' class='box enabled'><div class='closeMessageBox'></div><p class='messageBoxTitle'>Fehler</p><p class='messageBoxContent'>"+message+"</p></div>");
  $("#messages").append($content);;
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
$("#messages").on("click", ".closeMessageBox", function() {
  var close = $(this);
  var currentBox = $(this).parent();
  currentBox.removeClass("enabled");
  currentBox.addClass("disabled");
  setTimeout(function() {$(this).closest(".box").remove();}, 400);
});
createMessageBox("Test");
```

```css
.closeMessageBox {
  background-color: red;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messages"></div>
```

Comment: There's nothing in your code that tries to remove anything.

Comment: I corrected it, even though that's not the point

Comment: Then what IS the point? What's wrong with what you have? Why are you using `setTimeout`?

Comment: Just read the post. "the code for that isn't executed" - it doesn't matter what code is in there, the other half of the code is the problem. And using setTimeout is just as irrelevant. Jesus.

Comment: It's executed when I try it, see my answer. Can you make an executable snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: The setTimeout is relevant since it is WRONG! Lose the attitude. The code inside is WRONG. `this` is not what you think it is.

Comment: @epascarello Seriously? I really hope you're kidding, even though april fools day is over. **Even if** it's wrong, it doesn't matter, since it is NOT executed, which is the problem. And since we're on stackexchange, tell me why setTimeout is wrong?

Comment: It is called.  Add `console.log()` lines! `console.log(this);` Put on before the setTimeout and one after it. I see both being triggered. And I see the exact issue I talked about and what the answer below also talks about. Debugging 101.

Comment: I already tried debugging with console.log(). And if the code **before** setTimeout doesn't execute, the code after it doesn't either. I tried removing setTimeout anyway - didn't change anything.

Comment: You tried to eat a pizza before it was made. `console.log("I found:", $("#messages").length); $("#messages").on("click".....;` You can not attach events to an element before it exists on the page.

Comment: @epascarello Thank you very much for telling me this. So what is wrong with setTimeout? I'd really like to know that, too.

Comment: `this` is window, not the closeMessageBox html node

Comment: @epascarello thank you, but Barmar has already figured that out. Not to mention that it doesn't solve the problem, since it would've created an error in the console, which I could've worked with. That is not the case, since the code is **not executed**.

Comment: It would have not created an error in the console! The code would do nothing just like your snipplet above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `this` is not saved in closures. Use the local variable `close` instead.

```js
var messageBoxCount = 0;
function createMessageBox(message) {
  messageBoxCount++;
  var $content = $("<div id='messageBox"+messageBoxCount+"' class='box enabled'><div class='closeMessageBox'></div><p class='messageBoxTitle'>Fehler</p><p class='messageBoxContent'>"+message+"</p></div>");
  $("#messages").append($content);;
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
$("#messages").on("click", ".closeMessageBox", function() {
  var close = $(this);
  var currentBox = $(this).parent();
  currentBox.removeClass("enabled");
  currentBox.addClass("disabled");
  setTimeout(function() {close.closest(".box").remove();}, 400);
});
createMessageBox("Test");
```

```css
.closeMessageBox {
  background-color: red;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messages"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Your solution obviously seems to be correct. On my site, it still doesn't for some reason. Apparently, something outside this code is causing problems. Here is the link to the site: http://www.tdvk.de/lehvo/index.php?site=index
Maybe you'll find something

Comment: press one of the upvote buttons, the second time the error is going to show up.

Comment: Put your code inside `$(document).ready()`. Your Javascript block is before the body, so the `#messages` element doesn't exist when you try to bind the click handler.

Comment: Thank you, that's probably going to be the problem.